# Computation of semi-ampleness in blow-up of projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an arbitrary field (algebraically closed if necessary), $Y \to \mathbb{P}^2_k=:X$ be the blow-up of two closed points $p,q$ in $X$.

Writing $E=E_p \coprod E_q$ for the exceptional divisor. I would like to know, if the divisor $D=3H-2E_p-E_q$ is semi-ample, where $H\subseteq X$ is a hyperplane divisor.

If I am not wrong, the $D$ should be nef, but not ample. Unfortunately I am stuck computing the baselocus of some power of $D$.

Comment: Sections of $D$ on $Y$ correspond to plane cubics which are singular at $p$ and $q$. You can do this by taking a reducible cubic of three lines (colloquially called a **triangle** in this context); specifically, take the line connecting $p$ and $q$, plus any other line through $p$, plus any other line through $q$. Since this gadget has a node at both $p$ and $q$, its proper transform on $Y$ has precisely class $D$. Therefore the base locus is the proper transform of $\overline{pq}$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I just have not understand enough material about this geometric computations, but how do we recover the coefficients with this construction? Taking the strict transform of a curve in $X$, we shoud recover the coefficients at the exceptional divisors as multiplicities at $p$ and $q$, and the hyperplane coefficient should be the degree. So I would guess, that your cubic pulls back to $3H-2E_p-2E_q$?

Comment: That's the gist of it, although you should be able to see this directly from equations, i.e. if you plug the equations of the blowup at $(0,0)$ into $xy=0$ (here I'm working in the chart where $z=1$) you should be able to factor out the equation of the exceptional divisor with multiplicity $2$.